# How can i block other deployment while i am deploying by code in Codeship using Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano, codeship

I want to deploy my code but i don't want one my colleagues simultaneously deploy another code or push right after me. Any strategy that can block the deployment in Codeship with Capistrano?

Comment: Do you mean *simultaneously* or *after me*? Do you have multiple parallel jobs trying to deploy to the same environment? Why?

Comment: yes! in the same environment. Because we deploy individual branch and one of branches might get lost. So you meant the parallel jobs will not allow multi deployment already?